# python unittesting - functions depending on other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing

Is there a "correct" way to write unit tests for functions that rely on non-local functions (multi-module dependency tests).
e.g.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── main1.py
│   └── main2.py
├── tests
│   └── tests_main.py
```

```py
# /src/main1.py
import main2

def plusOne(number: int):
    return main2.addOne(number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(plusOne(1))
```

```py
# /src/main2.py
def addOne(number: int):
    return number + 1
```

```py
# tests/test_main.py
import unittest
import src.main1

class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case1(self):
        number = 1
        result = src.main1.plusOne(number)
        self.assertEqual(result, number + 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

You can run `python src/main.py` as you'd expected.
but when running tests `python -m unittest tests/tests_main.py`
There's an import error:

```
 File "/.../app/src/main1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import main2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main2'
```

---

The import statement in main1.py can be changed from `import main2` to `from . import main2` but this breaks running `python src/main.py` with a relative import error. i.e.

```
    from . import main2
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is there a correct way to manage imports to satisfy import requirements and avoid conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `python -m unittest tests/tests_main.py`, you actually load `main1.py` as a module instead of a script. The load logic is quite different between module and scripts.

When you run with `python -m`, the import "root" is always current directory. But we you run python without `-m` the "root" is the folder contains the script, e.g.. `src` in you first case. This cause your issue.

You can see the root path via `import sys; print(sys.path)`

The best solution I have is always run things as module:
change first line of `/src/main1.py` to absolute import:

```py
import src.main2
```

and

you need to call the code as module with `python -m src.main1` instead of `python src/main1.py`

Comment: Not a solution. specificity doesn't affect module visibility in this case. 
This just changes which module is unrecognized from `No module named 'main2'` its `No module named 'src'`.

Comment: My apology. Updated my answer. You actually need to do both things, change import and run with different way.